# Javafx 8 how to make mouse cursor invisible?

Tags: javafx-8, invisible, mouse-cursor

I am making a 2D shooting game on Javafx 8 and I would like to be able to make the cursor invisible so that I can replace it with crosshairs.

Is there anyway to make the mouse cursor invisible when it is on the scene?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

To change your cursor, you'd use the [`scene.setCursor(String)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/Scene.html#setCursor-javafx.scene.Cursor-) method.

**To change image**

Using a reference to your current scene, pass in `Cursor.cursor("url")` to `setCursor`:

```
scene.setCursor(Cursor.cursor("url"));
```

**To remove the cursor**

Using a reference to your current scene, pass in `Cursor.NONE` to `setCursor`:

```
scene.setCursor(Cursor.NONE);
```

You also might be interested in the `Cursor.CROSSHAIR` value

Comment: Thank you so much! That was indeed much simpler than I thought, AND there's a method to change the image, which makes everything even simpler.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Vince's response, you can use FXML to make the cursor disappear over a specific control or layout, e.g.:

```
<?import javafx.scene.Cursor?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.Pane?>
<Pane ...>
    <cursor>
        <Cursor fx:constant="NONE"/>
    </cursor>
    ...
</Pane>
```